# Is there an option in excel to automatically fill other second document base on the first one?

Tags: excel

I would like to ask if you know this:

I have excel document which contains list of people with dates and stuff for each day. So I am doingnew one each day, because sometimes i have to put different people, stuff etc. 
Check attachment

[image]

But I need to fill also this file, and I have a lot of copies because every person from the list have one, but it has same cells like name, date, weight etc.

Check attachment 2

[image]

Question. it possible to do something to automatically fill this file base on first one? 
Like each time I update the list, then this file ( one for every person )updates itself?

Comment: A screenshot of a picture of a paper printout of an excel sheet. This is a new one ;) At any rate, yes it's totally possible, but it won't be easy. This is something that could be accomplished through either some nasty `vlookup()` formulas or through a pretty complex VBA module. If you can focus this question down to a particular problem you are having besides "is this very complex requirement achievable" we may be able to offer more help. Right now this is too broad to answer effectively.

Comment: Haha I know but this screenshot was all what I got  honestly saying i have no clue how to do it but thanks for letting me know that this is possible in excel!